# How to proceed to work out this stats problem?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am working on a question/ problem that goes as follows:

[image: Question]

I thought that I had understood the concepts behind the question, however, when plugging my answers within the system, I was notified that all of them were wrong and I cannot figure out why.

I was hoping that someone could help me pinpoint my mistakes and guide me towards the correct answers.

> **Here is my work:**

> > Part (a)

Margin of Error, *E* $$= \frac{23.0132-22.6868}{2} =0.1632$$

$$E = z \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$0.1632 = z \times \frac{0.40}{\sqrt{26}}$$
$$ z = \frac{0.1632 \times \sqrt{26}}{0.40} = 2.0804$$

From the z table, 96.2511% is associated with the Confidence Interval provided

> > Part (b)

Since the Z score for 90% confidence interval is 1.645,

$$P(-1.645 < Z < 1.645) = 0.90$$

$$E = z \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = 1.645 \times
    \frac{0.40}{\sqrt{26}} = 0.12904$$

Confidence Interval for 90% is  $$ \mu \pm E = 22.85 \pm 0.12904
    =[22.720, 22.97904]$$

> > Part (c)

Since the Z score for 90% confidence interval is 2.576,

$$P(-2.576 < Z < 2.576) = 0.99$$

And, with the margin of error being the same as in part (a),

$$E = 0.1632$$
$$0.1632 = 2.576 \times \frac{0.40}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$n = \left( \frac{2.576 \times 0.40}{0.1632}\right)^2 = 39.86 \sim 40$$

Comment: Because $\sigma = 0.4$ is given, these are z-intervals and the t distribution is not relevant. Your answers for (a) and (b) seem OK. (c) Asks for 99% CI and you give answ for 90% CI. See no serious misunderstanding. // Sometimes online answering is a challenge. You have to use _exactly_ the same format the programmer had in mind. Also, some of the online materials are simply wrong. (Perhaps written in a hurry during the covid crisis by coaches who've lost their playing seasons and publisher advertising execs who last though about statistics 20 yrs ago, if then.)